# Can't install NLTK with setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I have installed python 2.7 and am trying to set up nltk to do some data analysis (I'm fairly new to the whole programming game). However, I can't seem to install nltk. I downloaded setuptools but it keeps telling me that it can't be found. Do any of you python masters know how to fix this? :)

```
$ python ez_setup.py
ez_setup.py:129: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
File "ez_setup.py", line 129
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict as VC_err:
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

$ sudo git clone     https://github.com/nltk/nltk.git
Password:
Cloning into 'nltk'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 48415, done.
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 48422 (delta 0), reused 2 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (48422/48422), 65.84 MiB | 1.78 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (32659/32659), done.
Checking connectivity... done

$ cd nltk

$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Comment: Is there an *.egg file where you downloaded setuptools?

Comment: The very second line makes me very suspictious that you are actually not running python2.7. What's the output of `python --version`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're compiling from the source? You can install via pip.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have python2.7-dev is not installed.
Try installing python2.7-dev as below and try running setup again.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
$ sudo python setup.py install
```